# EF 4 STE difference between context.Refresh() and context.[Entity].Include("NavigationProperty")

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

(1) Can someone please explain the difference between performing data access using the two different methods described below?

```
context.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, context.ParentEntity);
```

and

```
return (from pe in context.ParentEntity select pe).ToList();
```

(2) And for a more complicated example with child entities/navigation properties involved, are there any fundamental differences between these two calls:

```
context.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, context.ParentEntity);
context.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, context.ChildEntity);
```

and

```
return (from pe in context.ParentEntity.Include("ChildEntities") select pe).ToList();
```

(3) Finally, we have some code that performs a combination of the two methods:

```
context.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, context.ParentEntity.Include("ChildEntities"))
```

I'm trying to get my head wrapped around when one method should be used over another or if they are all functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the wrong ideas about `Refresh` and `Include`...

"`Refresh` has the dual purpose of allowing an object to be refreshed with data from the data source and being the mechanism by which conflicts can be resolved" (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx))

"`Include` specifies the related objects to include in the query results." (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx))

*So to answer your question*, `Refresh` is a void method and NOT a query... It is used to manage concurrency and resolve conflicts... I'm not sure if you were trying to get results back from this, but I can't imagine it worked very well!

Your `(from pe in context...` statements are [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) queries making use of the `Include` method, which (like it sounds) includes the specified objects in the query results.

Taking a look at the MSDN pages for the methods can usually help quite a bit when you're not sure what they are doing.

Hope this helped!